# How to send data as string and not json on axios post

Tags: c#, reactjs, api, .net-core, axios

I have question about sending string value on axios post. I will provide code below for better understanding.

### API CALL C# MVC .netcore

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Save(string Code, [FromBody]string notes)
        {
           ------
        }
```

so above it will get the data of string from FROMBODY

### REACT FRONT END USING AXIOS CALL

```
export const sendNote = async (Url, code, value) => {
  let Config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.post(
      Url + code + "/Notes", 
     value,
      Config
    );
    return { data: data };
  } catch (error) {
    return { data: error.message };
  }
};
```

So as you can see on the code above, I am trying to send the value which is a string to the api call on C# but I get many different error like 400 or 415. I researched it on google and they mostly put it on the json format.

So end it like "TEST" instead of {data: "TEST"}

Thank you

Comment: Since you want to send a string why do you  specify json content `Content-Type: application/json` This should be more like `Content-Type: application/text`.

Comment: @AntonKovachev Hi, thank you for your response and yes you are right I already tried using "application/text" but it still returns same error. When I run the api call separately it works. Well it still return error code 415....

Comment: Perhaps you can leave `Content-Type: application/json` and send a request body similar to this  one `{ notes: value }` And also inspect with the web developer tools what data exactly you are sending

Comment: @AntonKovachev Yes, I thought about sending it as json object like what you mentioned above, but api call created by backend developer here told me to send as string only so That is the reason why I am looking into sending the data as string.

Comment: @SamuelJungHwanPark did you found a solution?

Comment: @EgoPingvina Yes, I did thank your for checking if I got to work!

Comment: @AntonKovachev `application/text` is not a valid content-type. See http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#application.

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution that works for me.
The problem is in `Content-Type` header.

```
...
headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json-patch+json" },
data: JSON.stringify(data),
params,
...
```

I have the same controller's method. I checked which headers uses in `Swagger`.
It started working only after these changes.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, an axios call like this:

```
    var object = {
                    myInt: 123456,
                    myString: "ciao Mondo"
                }

   return await axios.post("/Test/testFromBody", object)
```

want a controller method in C# like this:

```
[HttpPost, Route("testFromBody")]
public async Task<ActionResult> testFromBody([FromBody] TestClass test)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

where TestClass is specular to the object which we sent.

If we do an axios call like this:

```
var formPayload = new FormData();
formPayload.append("myInt", 134)
formPayload.append("myString", 'Ciao mondo')
return await axios.post("/Test/testFromForm", formPayload)
```

the controller looks like:

```
[HttpPost, Route("testFromForm")]
public async Task<ActionResult> testFromForm([FromForm] int myInt, string myString)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

otherwhise

```
var foo = "ciao Mondo"
var bar = 2345

return await axios.post(`/Test/testFromQueryParemtri?myInt=${foo}&myString=${bar}`)
```

the C# method

```
    [HttpPost, Route("testFromQueryParemtri")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> testFromQueryParemtri([FromQuery] int myInt, string myString)
{
    return Ok();
}
```